# Visual Studio android emulator настройка сети

Tags: android, visual-studio, эмулятор, hyper-v

Имеется `Visual Studio android emulator` (свежая версия). Если (через `Hyper-V`) настроить сеть как внешнюю, то при запуске эмулятора происходит зависание (потом иногда ошибка о сбое). Если установить сеть как внутреннюю, то старт проходит нормально. Но сети нет.

Вопрос: как запустить эмулятор с возможностью доступа в интернет?

Answer (score 1):

Адаптер по умолчанию создается внутренний. Для работы с Visual Studio должно быть именно так. Если у вас есть DHCP-сервер, то интернет на эмуляторе должен быть.

Если у вас нет DHCP-сервера, то необходимо:

1. выключить виртуальную машину с эмулятором
2. добавить второй сетевой адаптер, где указать ваш внешний сетевой адаптер гипервизора
3. запустить эмулятор и в устройстве в настройках сети вызвать контекстное меню, переключиться с DHCP на статику и ввести параметры сети

Если все действия сделаны правильно, вы получите интернет в эмуляторе без DHCP.

Comment: Увы - не сработало. DHCP у меня активен на роутере.